# join multiple times in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

These are the 2 tables.
Tech_data:

```
Id Tech Agent1_id Agent2_ID
1  JAVA   1           2   
2  SQL    3           4
```

Agent_table

```
Id Name
1  Mike
2  John
3  Jim
4  Baron
```

I need to write a query to bring the below output

```
TECH_ID   Tech  Agent1_Name Agent2_Name
1         Java    Mike       John
2         SQL     Jim        Baron
```

I wrote LEFT OUTER JOIN ON tech_id=agent1_id, but i do not know how to join 2 ids in ON condition.

Comment: It looks like you want K union selects for your K columns. In this case K = 2. Point us to a fiddle so we can fill in details: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent having to do multiple joins to the same table, you can unpivot, join and then pivot (then if you had 50 ID columns you would still only need to perform one join):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e814ed/7)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Tech_data (Id, Tech, Agent1_id, Agent2_ID ) AS
SELECT 1,  'JAVA', 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  'SQL',  3, 4 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Agent_table ( Id, Name ) AS
SELECT 1,  'Mike' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  'John' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  'Jim' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,  'Baron' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.id,
         t.tech,
         t.num,
         a.name
  FROM   (
      SELECT *
      FROM   tech_data
      UNPIVOT ( Agent_ID FOR num IN ( Agent1_id AS 1, Agent2_id AS 2 ) )
    ) t
    INNER JOIN Agent_table a
    ON ( t.agent_id = a.id )
)
PIVOT ( MAX( name ) FOR num IN ( 1 AS Agent1_Name, 2 AS Agent2_Name ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e814ed/7/0)**:

```
| ID | TECH | AGENT1_NAME | AGENT2_NAME |
|----|------|-------------|-------------|
|  1 | JAVA |        Mike |        John |
|  2 |  SQL |         Jim |       Baron |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a second left outer join just like the one you have used, on the same table by giving them different aliases as follows.

```
select t.Id tech_id, t.tech, a1.name, a2.name
from tech_data t
left outer join agent_table a1 on a1.Id = t.agent1_id
left outer join agent_table a2 on a2.Id = t.agent2_Id;
```

Check the fiddle below: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73f02b/1

Comment: Good - this approach would scale nicely to a bunch of columns.

Comment: @roshan Thanks. Total rows in Tech table is 582 rows, after having these 2 joins, total rows fetched is 669. I added null check like : `a1.Id is not null or a2.Id is not null` but dint work.

Comment: @J_H I hope that is sarcastic. It will perform a table (or index) scan for each join so having 50 columns and performing one join for each will do 50 table (or index) scans of the `agent_table`. You can see that in the execution plan of the linked SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @MT0 sorry, my meaning was it would scale in the sense of having clear easily read code when additional columns were added, rather than in the machine sense. The requirement in the problem statement is a bit horrible and non-relational, but the join_K_times approach is a clear way of expressing it. I like the unpivot approach, which offers less clarity yet greater machine performance.